# Using apt-get how to check have installed latest version ?

Tags: apt

Hello im just new for Linux

I know that  `sudo apt-get`   is for installing application

but how I would know that I have installed the latest version of the application

for example `apt-get install sun-java6-jdk`

is there an option to upgrade or see the latest version

or its ok to install an old version the application and Linux will upgrade it for me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `apt-cache policy` command:

```
$ apt-cache policy openjdk-6-jre
openjdk-6-jre:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6b32-1.13.4-4ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
     6b32-1.13.4-4ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://aptmirror.fqdn/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://aptmirror.fqdn/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

It says that I don't have any version installed, and of the available versions, `6b32-1.13.4-4ubuntu0.14.04.1` (the candidate) will be installed if I do `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre`.

Even if you have it installed already, if you do `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre`, the latest version available (according to the Candidate field above) will be installed. So an installed package will be upgraded.

> Can I stop an installation while it's running in the terminal by clicking something on the keyboard?

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to exit from most programs, including `sudo` password prompts and `apt-get`. It's a very bad idea to do so with `apt-get`. You can cancel while the download is in progress, but once the installation begins, don't do so.

Comment: this help .. i have one more question please .. for example now when write sudo for anything .. linux will ask you for password .. if I see the option to input the password for admin .. is there something in the  keybored to click to exit or close instead if i changed my mind to not input a password? .. also my second question Can I stop an installation while it's running in the terminal by clicking something in the keybored ?

Comment: @boudi I have updated the answer.